# How do I make this Python program interactive?

Tags: python, interactive

I am trying to modify the example found here (https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-dynamic-visualization-with-python-animations-and-interactive-plots-f72a7fb69245) to run outside of a Jupyter notebook.

The program below produces a *.gif that is animated but not interactive. Can anyone find the error?

```
#Based on the example here
# https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-dynamic-visualization-with-python-animations-and-interactive-plots-f72a7fb69245

# # Import packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

# Fermi-Dirac Distribution
def fermi(E: npt.NDArray[np.float64], E_f: float, T: float) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    k_b = 8.617 * (10**-5) # eV/K
    return 1/(np.exp((E - E_f)/(k_b * T)) + 1)

# Animation function
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    y = fermi(x, 0.5, T[i])
    f_d.set_data(x, y)
    f_d.set_color(colors(i))
    temp.set_text(str(int(T[i])) + ' K')
    temp.set_color(colors(i))

# Update values
def update(val):
    Ef = s_Ef.val
    T = s_T.val
    f_d.set_data(x, fermi(x, Ef, T))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# Create sliders
s_Ef = Slider(ax=ax_Ef, label='Fermi Energy ', valmin=0, valmax=1.0,
              valfmt=' %1.1f eV', facecolor='#cc7000')
              
s_T = Slider(ax=ax_T, label='Temperature ', valmin=100, valmax=1000, 
             valinit=100, valfmt='%i K', facecolor='#cc7000')

# General plot parameters
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 18

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False

mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['ytick.major.width'] = 2

# Temperature values
T = np.linspace(100, 1000, 10)

# Get colors
colors = mpl.colormaps['copper'].resampled(8)

# Create figure and add axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Add legend
labels = ['100 K', '200 K', '300 K', '400 K', '500 K', '600 K', 
          '700 K', '800 K', '900 K', '1000 K']

ax.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, -0.1), loc='lower left', 
          frameon=False, labelspacing=0.2)

# Create variable reference to plot
f_d, = ax.plot([], [], linewidth=2.5)

# Add text annotation and create variable reference
temp = ax.text(1, 1, '', ha='right', va='top', fontsize=24)

# Create main axis
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.75)

# Create axes for sliders
ax_Ef = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.85, 0.4, 0.05])
ax_Ef.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
ax_Ef.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

ax_T = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.92, 0.4, 0.05])
ax_T.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
ax_T.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

# Plot default data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Ef_0 = 0.5
T_0 = 100
y = fermi(x, Ef_0, T_0)
f_d, = ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.5)

s_Ef.on_changed(update)
s_T.on_changed(update)

# Create animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=range(len(T)), interval=500, repeat=True)

# Save and show animation
ani.save('AnimatedPlot.gif', writer='pillow', fps=2)
```

Comment: For proper guidance, you need to explain more what you mean by 'to run outside of a Jupyter notebook'? Is it just that you want it to run on the internet without the notebook cruft appearing around it? Or maybe you didn't realize you can probably leave it in the notebook form but change how the notebook is interacted with so that it looks more like an app or dashboard? Search 'voila gallery' to get an idea of that. Conversely, how do you expect it to be interactive if you aren't running it inside something that provides a graphical user interface with which you or others can interact with it?

Comment: @Wayne Thank you! Your answer answered my question!  I did not realize that I need to add an additional package.  I have added additional information above.

Answer (score 0):

@Wayne pointed out that I need to add an additional package so that the slider bars are interactive.  Here is a useful resource

https://towardsdatascience.com/4-python-packages-to-create-interactive-dashboards-d50861d1117e

Comment: Those first two in the list, ipywidgets and Voila, are targeted for use with Jupyter. And all those are targeted at browser-based, primarily. If you want to be separate from Jupyter and running on a local machine not in a browser, there's also things like tkinter and PySimpleGui, see https://twitter.com/driscollis/status/1598028839845826580 for that latter.

Comment: Plus, you may want to read about [this static nbviewer-served version of this notebook](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1) that has interactive plots, even though there is no active kernel. (Note you can slide & use the buttons to play the animation.) How that is made is described in the bottom section of a notebook you can run by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) & pressing `launch binder`. In [static form here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder/blob/master/index.ipynb). Search 'scrub'.

Comment: [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) can be pointed at any notebook available on the web and has more abilities than the rendering GitHub offers, which, despite recent improvements, remains best considered a preview. The URL of the nbviewer rendering can be shared to provide a way to share notebooks that are largely static, but can have interactive elements. (You cannot run Python there but the javascript based abilities can remain working.)